# Inverse of number of the form $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{c}{d}\sqrt{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am looking to find the inverse of a number with the form:

$$\frac{x_1}{x_2} + \frac{x_3}{x_4}\sqrt{2}$$
where $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$, and $x_4$ are integers, $x_2 \ne 0$, and $x_4 \ne 0$.

I have tried using polynomial factoring but could not find a suitable solution.

What I did:

$$\left(\frac{x_1}{x_2} + \frac{x_3}{x_4}\sqrt{2}\right)^{-1}=\frac{x_2x_4}{x_1x_4+x_3x_2\sqrt{2}}.$$

Then I did the usual steps for polynomial division and got this result:

$$\frac{x_1}{x_2}-\frac{x_3x_2^{2}}{x_1^{2}x_4+x_1x_3x_2\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{2}.$$

As you see it does not have the form $\frac{x_1}{x_2} + \frac{x_3}{x_4}\sqrt{2}$ because of the $\sqrt{2}$ in the denominator of the second term. Where should I go from there?

Comment: Rationalize the denominator in $\frac{x_2x_4}{x_1x_4+x_3x_2\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: I don't understand why you have tagged this with [tag:data-structure].  Can you please either clarify why you have done this or find a more appropriate tag? [tag:algebra-precalculus], for example?

Comment: $(a+b\sqrt2)(x+y\sqrt2)=1\iff ax+2by=1\text{ and }ay+bx=0$ This system gives $$x=\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}\\y=\frac{-b}{a^2-2b^2}$$ Just replace $a$ and $b$ by the rationals.

Comment: Thanks @Piquito.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Done. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply top and bottom by $a-b\sqrt{2}$ to get:

$$\frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{2}}=\frac{a-b\sqrt{2}}{a^2-2b^2}=\frac{a}{a^2-2b^2}-\frac{b}{a^2-2b^2}\sqrt{2}.$$

If $a$ and $b$ are rational, then $a^2-2b^2 \neq 0$ and both coefficients of the result will also be rational.  Just substitute $a=\frac{x_1}{x_2}, b=\frac{x_3}{x_4}$ and simplify the resulting fractions.

Comment: Thank you. Accepted answer.